# Obtener resultados en Eloquent filtrando por un campo de una tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos modelos Eloquent: `Company` y `Employee` con una relación donde
una empresa puede tener 1 o muchos empleados y un empleado sólo puede pertenecer a una empresa, entonces en los modelos tengo las relaciones:

En `Company`:

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Employee');
}
```

En `Employee`:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id');
}
```

Los empleados pueden estar activos o no, tengo un campo `active` que puede
guardar 0 o 1, 1 para activo.

Estoy intentando **recuperar todas las empresas con empleados activos y sólo activos**.
Si una empresa no tiene empleados activos no debe estar en el resultado.

### Editado:

He probado:

```
public static function getOnlyActive($companies) // Company::with('employees')->get()
{
    // Prueba 1

    // foreach ($companies as $company) {
    //     $employees = $company->employees;
    //     foreach ($employees as $key => $employee) {
    //         if ($employee->active === 0) {
    //             unset($employees[$key]);
    //         }
    //     }

    //     $customer->employees = $employees;
    // }


    // Prueba 2

    foreach ($companies as $key => $company) {
        $companies[$key] = $company->with(['employees' => function ($employees) {
            foreach ($employees as $key => $employee) {
                $employees[$key] = $employee->where('ok', '=', 1)->first();
            }
        }]);

        $company->employees = $company->employees->values();
    }


    return $companies;
}
```

### Editado:

Para poder reproducir el problema:

**Migraciones**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateEmployeesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->smallInteger('active')->default(1);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');

            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('employees');
    }
}
```

**Seeders**

```
<?php

use App\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CompanySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $company = new Company();
        $company->name = 'ACME';
        $company->save();

        $company = new Company();
        $company->name = 'Xfr';
        $company->save();

        $company = new Company();
        $company->name = 'Linux Inc';
        $company->save();
    }
}

<?php

use App\Models\Employee;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class EmployeeSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Foo';
        $employee->company_id = 1;
        $employee->save();

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Baz';
        $employee->company_id = 1;
        $employee->save();

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Qux';
        $employee->active = 0;
        $employee->company_id = 1;
        $employee->save();

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Quux';
        $employee->active = 0;
        $employee->company_id = 1;
        $employee->save();

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Quuz';
        $employee->company_id = 1;
        $employee->save();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'John Doe';
        $employee->active = 0;
        $employee->company_id = 2;
        $employee->save();

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Grault';
        $employee->company_id = 2;
        $employee->save();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Waldo';
        $employee->active = 0;
        $employee->company_id = 3;
        $employee->save();

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->name = 'Fred';
        $employee->active = 0;
        $employee->company_id = 3;
        $employee->save();
    }
}
```

**Modelos**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Employee');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución sería:

```
$empresasConEmpleadosActivos = Company::whereHas('employees', fn($query) => $query->whereActive(1))
                ->with('employees')
                ->get();
```

Lo único que hacemos de acuerdo a como lo indica la [propia doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) es construir un *constraint* por medio de una función dentro del método *`whereHas`* misma en la cual pasamos un `where` donde filtramos los empleados activos y posterior cargamos a todos los empleados con ayuda de `with`.

De esta manera descartamos empresas que no tengan empleados y también aquellas que solo tienen empleados inactivos.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu solución, me devuelve toas las empresas con sus empleados activos, o ningún empleado, sino tiene ninguno activo. No cumple la condición: "Si una empresa no tiene empleados activos no debe estar en el resultado.", voy a ver si veo como funciona y puedo apañarla. Añado migraciones y otras clases a la pregunta para poder duplicar el problema.

Comment: @Orici tienes razón, me di el tiempo de replicar tu ejemplo con los datos provisto y efectivamente el filtro no era el adecuado, espero esta edición ayude en caso contrario esperemos los aportes de otros o en caso de ser así tu propia respuesta

Comment: Ahora perfecto, resuelves la pregunta. He visto que ***no la plantee del todo bien porque tampoco quería empleados inactivos en esas empresas...*** Voy a añadir una respuesta recapitulando tus respuestas y añadiendo también esta condición. Luego no se porque las funciones flecha me dan ***error de sintaxis***, tengo PHP 8.0.1, en ***Tinker*** funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: @Orici, en estos casos lo recomendable entonces es que sea tu respuesta la aceptada, pues está contiene l solución final

Comment: Pero tu respuesta resuelve mi pregunta, mi respuesta extiende la solución más allá de lo que pregunte.

Answer (score 1):

Pregunta original:

> Recuperar todas las empresas con empleados activos y sólo activos. Si una empresa no tiene empleados activos no debe estar en el resultado.

Con la última respuesta que me dio [BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/423330/20709) está solucionada, además para ***obtener esas empresas sólo con sus empleados activos***, la solución la tengo combinando ambas:

```
$companiesFinal = Company::with([
    'employees' => (function ($query) {
        $query->whereActive(1);
    })
])->whereHas('employees', function ($query) {
    $query->whereActive(1);
})->get();
```

Recapitulando, ya que añadí bastante código, pongo las respuestas en un controlador, las dos primeras *queries* son las que me dio [BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/423330/20709), *reescribí las funciones flecha en anónimas normales porque en el navegador tenía un error de sintaxis (PHP 8.0.1), en [Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#tinker) funcionan correctamente las originales.*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Company;

class QueriesController extends Controller
{

    public function companies()
    {
        $companies = Company::has('employees')
            ->with([
                'employees' => (function ($query) { $query->whereActive(1); })
            ])->get();

        $companies2 = Company::whereHas('employees', function ($query) { $query->whereActive(1); })
            ->with('employees')
            ->get();

        $companiesFinal = Company::with([
            'employees' => (function ($query) {
                $query->whereActive(1);
            })
        ])->whereHas('employees', function ($query) {
            $query->whereActive(1);
        })->get();


        dump('Todas las empresas y sus empleados activos, o ninguno sino hay empleados activos');
        dump($companies->pluck('name'), $companies->pluck('employees'));

        dump('Todas las empresas con empleados activos y sus empleados (activos e inactivos)');
        dump($companies2->pluck('name'), $companies2->pluck('employees'));

        dump('Todas las empresas con empleados activos y sus empleados (solo activos)');
        dump($companiesFinal->pluck('name'), $companiesFinal->pluck('employees'));
    }
}
```

Y la ruta:

```
Route::get('companies-with-active-employees', 'QueriesController@companies')
    ->name('companies.employees.active');
```